# How to make use of variable on translate3d function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on my portfolio, I have a function called translate3d(0,10px,0) in javascript. My question is what if I want to out variable instead of 10px to avoid hard cording, how would i do it?I have tried translate3d(0,a,0) assuming a in a variable whose value is 10px (like this a="10px";) but it wasn't shoing any changesto the page and also no error  were seen in console. Thanks in advance.

```
// This is how the function looks like
function levelBox(){
    setTimeout(function (){
    e1.style.webkitTransitionDuration = "1s";
    e1.style.webkitTransitionTimingFunction = "ease-out";
    e1.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0, 'a', 0)";
}, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass `translate3d` function as a string to `webkitTransform` and even `a`

try this

```
function levelBox(){
    setTimeout(function () {
    var a = "10px";
    var value = translate3d(0, a, 0);
    e1.style.webkitTransitionDuration = "1s";
    e1.style.webkitTransitionTimingFunction = "ease-out";
    e1.style.webkitTransform = value;
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it as follows:

```
function levelBox(_x, _y, _z){
    setTimeout(function (){
    e1.style.webkitTransitionDuration = "1s";
    e1.style.webkitTransitionTimingFunction = "ease-out";
    e1.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d("+_x+"px, "+_y+"px, "+_z+"px)";
}, 0);
}
```